# Unable to remove the Notification in Android lollipop even after clicking the notification even after using AUTOCANCEL

Tags: android

Main theme of my app is to send notification for the user that the new offers available in store using PushNotification using Google Cloud Messaging

```
private void sendNotification(Context context, String message) {

SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MYAPP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

int uniqueNumber = this.getSharedPreferences("MYAPP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("uniqueNumber", 0);
    Log.d("GCM: GN", "Message: " + message);

    uniqueNumber = ++uniqueNumber;
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent intent = new Intent(GCMIntentService.this,OpenActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(OpenActivity.EXTRA_KEY, "navigate");
    intent.putExtra(OpenActivity.GET_NOTIFY_ID_EXTRA, uniqueNumber);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, pendingIntent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS|Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL  ;

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(uniqueNumber, notification);

    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putInt("uniqueNumber", uniqueNumber);
    prefsEditor.commit();

}
```

Guys,this piece of code is not working only in Lollipop.

Any help Appreciated...

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the Support Library's [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) or even [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html)? The code you're using is 4 years deprecated.

Comment: No particular reason.I have  used Notification.Builder earlier but i got the same same issue..

Comment: Same issue with  NotificationCompat.Builder  in my App.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works fine for me as the same I have implemented to my project.

```
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

If it's not working fine, please clear your intent tasks using below code.

```
Intent notificationIntent;
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution but it's not working...

Comment: hey, for that claer your intent flags and it's working fine.

Comment: Hey,even after using that flags also that issue is not resolved......

Answer (score 0):

Please add this and try it into your code.

NOTIFICATION_COUNT = 10;

```
private void generateNotification(final String message, final String title, final String userType, final String userId) {

        Log.e("message:", message);
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent;

        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, GroupMessagesActivity.class);

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        long[] pattern = { 0, 100, 1500 };
        v.vibrate(pattern, -1);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_COUNT, notification);
        NOTIFICATION_COUNT = 1 + NOTIFICATION_COUNT;
    }
```

Comment: Just define NOTOFICATION_COUNT =10 globally.

Answer (score 0):

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Please try this.

Comment: i have used these notification flags also..

I am  having issue with the pending intent...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your activity theme.If you are using your own custom theme try replacing it with one provided by android.